# crazy drag&drop in sencha extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs6-classic

I am a beginner in sencha extjs.

I have a problem with drag&drop of sencha extjs, my code is based on the official example of drag & drop but it does not work completely, that is, it only works by dragging files left-right, right-left and bottom-up, when I drag from top to bottom, it goes crazy.

Note: the official example works by dragging files from either side of the panel.

> Code for the view

```
Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.drag.File', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'drag.file',

    controller: 'drag.file',

    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Fit'
    ],

    title: 'File Drag',
    draggable: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    layout: 'fit',

    bodyCls: 'drag-file-ct',

    html: '<div class="drag-file-label">' +
        'Drop some files here' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="drag-file-icon"></div>'
});
```

> Code for controllerView

```
Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.drag.FileViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.drag.file',

    requires: ['Ext.drag.Target'],

    afterRender: function(view) {
        var body = view.body;

        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            this.target = new Ext.drag.Target({
                element: body,
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    dragenter: this.onDragEnter,
                    dragleave: this.onDragLeave,
                    drop: this.onDrop
                }
            });
        } else {
            body.down('.drag-file-label').setHtml(
                'File dragging is not supported by your browser'
            );
            body.el.addCls('nosupport');
        }
    },

    onDragEnter: function() {
        this.getView().body.addCls('active');
        //console.log("Enter");    
    },

    onDragLeave: function() {
        this.getView().body.removeCls('active');
        //console.log("Fuera");    
    },

    onDrop: function(target, info) {
        var view = this.getView(),
            body = view.body,
            icon = body.down('.drag-file-icon');

        body.removeCls('active').addCls('dropped');
        icon.addCls('fa-spin');

        var me = this,
            files = info.files,
            len = files.length,
            s;

        if (len > 1) {
            s = 'Dropped ' + len + ' files.';
        } else {
            s = 'Dropped ' + files[0].name;
        }

        Ext.toast({
            html: s,
            closable: false,
            align: 't',
            slideInDuration: 400,
            minWidth: 400
        });

        me.timer = Ext.defer(function() {
            if (!view.destroyed) {
                icon.removeCls('fa-spin');
                icon.fadeOut({
                    callback: function() {
                        body.removeCls('dropped');
                        icon.setOpacity(1);
                        icon.show();
                    }
                });
            }
            me.timer = null;
        }, 2000);
    },

    destroy: function() {
        Ext.undefer(this.timer);
        this.target = Ext.destroy(this.target);
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code for the view is the same as the controller, can you fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. fixed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you missed the extra CSS rules. For example, you must suppress all pointer events otherwise dragging on top of the icon container will cause a "dragleave" event to be fired.

Here are the complete set of rules you will need, and fiddle example: 
Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hac

```
.drag-file-ct .x-innerhtml {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.drag-file-fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.drag-file-label {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.drag-file-icon {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  font-size: 64px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.active .drag-file-icon {
  display: block;
}
.active .drag-file-icon:after {
  content: "\f058";
  color: #8BC34A;
}
.dropped .drag-file-icon {
  display: block;
}
.dropped .drag-file-icon:after {
  content: "\f013";
  color: #9E9E9E;
}
.nosupport .drag-file-icon {
  display: block;
}
.nosupport .drag-file-icon:after {
  content: "\f119";
  color: #9E9E9E;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem goes even further, it turns out that I have this structure Window-> form-> container (drag & drop). How can I find the reference to the panel so that the drag & drop is executed there? [myfiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hah)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have any of the items that should work. It doesn't even have the main html structure that has the `drag-file-icon` or the `bodyCls: 'drag-file-ct',` described in your initial question. Can you update your fiddle and verify it's complete?

Comment: Fixed it. But I said, it does not work because I can not get the view. Any ideas to make it work with this view structure?

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, using the `reference` to lookup the panel, and updated the controller code to look for the reference instead of `this.getView()` which will point to the window

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme Lopes. It woks. I was trying with this.lookupReference but it did not work. What is the difference between this.lookup ('reference') and this.lookupReference ('reference')?

Comment: None, if you change all the references there from `lookup` to `lookupReference` nothing will change. See here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-lookup - It's just a shorthand :)

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ha9)

I also had this problem in the fiddle at the beginning, but then i replaced the target element `body` with element id `asdasd` and it worked. Seems like its about layers.